# How to put two words, one above the other, and a curley bracket on the same line?

Tags: css

Is it possible, using CSS, to display two words, “Manden” and “Kvinden”, and the curley bracket on the same line, as seen on the picture? Does anyone knows a website where to look for a solution?

It's danish poetry from 1811. An image wouldn't do; it must be possible to search for the text. This is my xml-code:

```
<lg>
   <l>Naar det seer, hvordan med Helvedkulde</l>
   <l>Læses uopløselige Baand,</l>
   <l>Seer før <span><span rend="top">Manden</span> <span rend="down">Kvinden</span></span> lagdes under,</l>
(...)
</lg>
```

[See the printed version here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Jzc.jpg)

Comment: I seem to remember the same question (with same image) asked once yesterday.

Comment: @KSR When an answer is "the right one for the question", your are supposed to accept that answer, to show future users which answer were the preferred one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/zvpKvd

It's possible with the use of absolute position(and probably a few other ways) Heres a start to it for the curly bracket i would probably just use `:after` along with `content` then just mess around with the positioning.

```css
.wordContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  /*whatever dimensions you want*/
  top: 8px;
}
.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
.down {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<lg>
  <l>Naar det seer, hvordan med Helvedkulde</l>
  <l>Læses uopløselige Baand,</l>
  <l>Seer før
    <span class="wordContainer">
      <span rend="top">Manden</span>
      <span rend="down">Kvinden</span>
    </span>&nbsp; lagdes under,</l>
  (...)
</lg>
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample using `sup`/`sub`.

```css
span {
  position: relative;
}
sup {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 14px;
  top: -1px;
}
sub {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;  
  top: -8px;
}
sub:after {
  content: "}";
  font-size: 240%;
  top: -5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<lg>
  <l>Naar det seer, hvordan med Helvedkulde</l>
  <l>Læses uopløselige Baand,</l>
  <l>Seer før <span><sup>Manden </sup><sub>Kvinden</sub></span> lagdes under,</l>
  (...)
</lg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am possibly a little late to the party with my solution but I couldn't help but think there needed to be an alternative to using absolute positioning. This is working well for a logo I made with a similar layout. Create a container and float three boxes left. Box one contains a bracket, box 2 contains your text and box three contains your closing bracket.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <style>

        .logo {
            width: auto;
            height: 100px;
            background: #ffffff;
            float: left;
        }

        .bracket {
            clear: none;
            float: left;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .bracket h1 {
            clear: left;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .title {
            clear: none;
            float: left;
        }

        .title h1 {
            clear: left;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

    </style>
</head>



<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <div class="bracket">
            <h1>{</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <h1>word</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="bracket">
            <h1>}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```